# Adding Browser Bookmarks using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bookmarks

I have an ASP.NET web page having a button in it. Clicking the button, a bookmark should be saved in the browser and when the user clicks the bookmark, it should surf to http://google.com.

How do I make sure that it works with almost all the standard browsers or at least with IE, Mozilla Firefox, Opera and Google Chrome.

Another case, I create a 2nd bookmark also in the same way. But when the user clicks upon the 2nd bookmark, it should run a piece of JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this piece of code which works for IE, Firefox and Opera (unfortunately it doesn't work for Google Chrome).

```
function bookmark()
{
    var title = 'Google';
    var url = 'http://google.com';

    if (document.all) // Check if the browser is Internet Explorer
        window.external.AddFavorite(url, title);

    else if (window.sidebar) //If the given browser is Mozilla Firefox
        window.sidebar.addPanel(title, url, "");

    else if (window.opera && window.print) //If the given browser is Opera
    {
        var bookmark_element = document.createElement('a');
        bookmark_element.setAttribute('href', url);
        bookmark_element.setAttribute('title', title);
        bookmark_element.setAttribute('rel', 'sidebar');
        bookmark_element.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: But this will (as I already explained) only add a sidebar for Firefox. And unforunately there is NO solution for Chrome or Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done for security reasons. It used to be possible using a proprietary IE command but I think that ended in IE 7. Definitely impossible in the others.

[Related discussion on Mozilla Developer Central](https://developer.mozilla.org/Talk:En/DOM/Window.sidebar)

Comment: Or at least giving an option for the user to add a bookmark i.e. is it possible to ask the user's permission to add it?

Comment: @Arjun I think this (asking the user's permission) is what happens nowadays when you call `window.external.AddFavorite` in IE. I know of no other way to do this other than ask the user to please press Ctrl+D.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox as far as I know there is currently no function that adds a regular bookmark. Only a sidebar bookmark can be created in Firefox.

Here you can find a script that works for most browsers: http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/01/add-to-favorites-ie-bookmark-firefox.html

As you can see at this line:

```
window.sidebar.addPanel(title, url,"");
```

it only adds a sidebar entry for Firefox, which is not very user friendly.

Comment: Another solution would be to use something like http://www.addthis.com which will give the user even more options to bookmark a page as he might not sit on his on PC to use a social bookmarking plugin in his browser.

Answer (score 1):

For FireFox no need to set any javascript for the bookmark, only an anchor tag with **title** and **rel="sidebar"** can do this functionality

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" title="Google" rel="sidebar">Bookmark This Page</a>
```

I have tested it on FF9