# get "browser is not defined" on adding bookmark in firefox using bookmarks.create

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, bookmarks

I'm trying to add a bookmark in my ASP.net MVC application, after using the following code I get "bowser is not defined" error.

Previous method which use "addpanel" function don't work any more (like: [Adding Browser Bookmarks using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965128/adding-browser-bookmarks-using-javascript))

here is my sample code:
https://jsfiddle.net/Spyknight2004/wvo98t4j/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".bookmarkme").click(function () {
    browser.bookmarks.create({
        title: document.title,
        url: location.href
    });
});});
```

I'm looking for an answer that works on known browsers (at least chrome and fire fox)

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use Chrome or Firefox for example, 
you should use `chrome` instead of `browser`.

According to MDN web docs:

> Note that this is different from Google Chrome's extension system, which uses the chrome namespace instead of browser

Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API)

Comment: Dear @zb22 , unfortunately that doesn't work, if you replace 'bowser' by 'chrome' you'll get 'chrome is not defined' error (you can check it on aforementioned fiddle). Is there any further attempt needed?

Comment: Does anybody have better advice?